# Stubbing a method with three arguments using mockito

Tags: mockito

I want to make a stub of a method with three arguments using Mockito, but I am getting null pointer exception

```
say A(String str, Object[] args, Integer.class)
```

for this I am doing

```
Mockito.when(
    jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        Mockito.anyString(), 
        Mockito.eq(args), 
        Mockito.eq(Integer.class)
    )
).thenReturn(1);
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at no.dnb.vaap.customer.infrastructure.repository.CustomerRepositoryImpl.checkMobileNumberExists(CustomerRepositoryImpl.java:21)
    at no.dnb.vaap.customer.infrastructure.repository.CustomerRepositoryImplTest.testCheckMobileNumberExists(CustomerRepositoryImplTest.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: where is the stack trace

Comment: Is jdbcTemplate a mock or a spied instance?

Comment: @LorenzoMurrocu : jdbc template is a mock one

Comment: @PrinceVarshney, how the mock is instantiated?

Comment: @LorenzoMurrocu : In test file by including mock annotations before it
 private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate ;   In main file the same is autowired

Comment: @PrinceVarshney, looking at the stack, it seems that the mock is not properly injected in to the tested class' instance. Maybe if you share the test class I can help

Comment: Based on the stack trace it looks like your error occurs in CustomerRepositoryImpl.java line 21. Can you please show us that code and the code before it (particularly where the arguments are set)?

Comment: Try changing `Mockito.eq(args)` to `args`, and `Mockito.eq(Integer.class)` to `Integer.class`

Comment: @DavidGermain : It wont work as all three arguments should be same...like either all three should be raw(Integer.class) or all three should be mockito converted(Mockito.eq(Integer.class))...

Comment: @LorenzoMurrocu,@JeffBowman: I am unable to add the code here.. tell me how to add...

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i changed Mockito.eq(args) to matchers.eq(args).. I dont know how it worked but i think mockito.eq(args) check for the references ..and matchers.eq(args) for the value..  is it. ??